# How to do sort Chinese column in Hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, sorting, hql, chinese-locale

I got a problem when I was sorting customer list for the Chinese column with Hibernate, firstly, I tried to sort them by the simple HQL:

```
String hql = "FROM CUSTOMER ORDER BY name DESC";
```

I found the retrieved list didn't meet our requirement, I want to sort them with 26 letter spells, and then I googled the solution that it can be solved by **SQL** like:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY convert(name using gbk) DESC";
```

I posted it on MySQL command line and it selected the right-sorting result, but right now It still doesn't solve my problem since It doesn't work in Hibernate and I just want to use Hibernate (**HQL**) to query, so is there any way to do it? Or must I should develop a new database dialect to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the answer, it will work for Ya!

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This, it might work for u as well, works for me!

```
SELECT * FROM customer  WHERE CONVERT(name USING gb2312) > '明'; 
SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY CONVERT(name USING gb2312);
```

> The latter implicitly uses gb2312_chinese_ci but you could name
>   another one for that charset, too.

Comment: Can I use CONVERT method in HQL?